# faster array cleaning method in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

What's faster for cleaning an array in actionscript 3?

```
myArray = [];
```

or

```
myArray.length = 0;
```

and why is faster? exist a better method than these? ...

Comment: If you need to do this so often the (propably tiny by themselves) speed differences will actually become noticeable, you're propably doing something very wrong. And even ignoring that, I bet there are a dozen places where you can optimize much (as in, many orders of magnitude) more.

Comment: I would guess the second option, because the first is an instantiation.

Comment: in the first one, you're actually creating a new array and assigning it to the myArray variable. in the second, you're resetting the length

Comment: wouldn't myArray = null; then myArray = new Array(); be best?

Comment: That's redundant. Setting a variable to null de-references the object, but so does sticking a new object in the variable. Either way, the point is the reference is no longer pointing to the first object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following test program:

```
var array:Array = [];
var start:int = getTimer();
for (var index:int = 0; index < 10000; index++)
{
    array.push(4);
    array = [];
    //array.length = 0;
}
var end:int = getTimer();
trace (end - start);
```

Using .length = 0 reports 10 milliseconds. Using array = [] reports 21 milliseconds. Clearly, doing .length = 0 is much faster. Additionally, doing array = [] may lead to earlier/more frequent garbage collections as it is probably performing a heap allocation. Garbage collection slows down the application at a later time.

.length = 0 wins for multiple reasons.

Comment: Thanks, a pretty sharp answer.